# Is there a shortcut to open the Bluetooth quick menu in Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, windows-11

In Windows 11, double-clicking the Bluetooth icon in the system tray opens the menu in the below screenshot. Is there a way to directly open this menu with a keyboard shortcut? If not, then is there a command that works via the Run menu or a command prompt, which I could then map to a keyboard shortcut using AutoHotkey?

Here is what I've tried so far:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - This worked in Windows 10, but unfortunately in Windows 11 it opens the Cast menu instead.
- Run command `ms-settings:bluetooth` - This command opens the full Bluetooth settings menu instead of the quick connect menu.
- Run command `ms-settings:connecteddevices` - Same as above.
- Run command `bthprops.cpl` - Same as above.

[image: Bluetooth quick menu]

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've found is that <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> [will open quick settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_11), though it's still an extra click from there to open the list of bluetooth devices vs how it worked in Windows 10.

Note the menu to choose Bluetooth devices from quick settings was only recently added to Windows 11, [starting with insider builds in February 2022](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/25/22951225/microsoft-windows-11-bluetooth-quick-settings-insider-testing-build), so if you don't see it make sure you're on the latest version of Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

The following toolset can help :
[Bluetooth Command Line Tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools).

You may use the `btdiscovery` command to list all Bluetooth devices with
their MAC address, then create batch scripts with shortcuts to connect or
disconnect individual devices that were previously paired.

Connect example:

```
btcom -c -b aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff -s110b
```

Disconnect:

```
btcom -r -b aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff -s110b
```

Answer (score 1):

### An advanced Logitech mouse is a solution:

If you have an advanced Logitech mouse, such as the MX Master 3 (which is what I have), then you can attach a smart action to one of the buttons on the mouse within their Logi Options+ program.  The advanced mouse comes with multiple buttons and scroll options that you can customize pretty significantly.

### Programming the Mouse:

The MX Master 3 has a button on top originally designated for changing the scroll wheel speed, but I have programmed it to open the Bluetooth devices using the steps below.

1. In Windows, click the quick action toolbar next to the time/date.
2. Select the pencil icon to edit the quick action icons and rearrange the Bluetooth icon to be the first item in the top left corner of the menu.
3. Open the Logi Options+ program, choose the MX Master 3 mouse, then "BUTTONS", and then the physical button on the mouse image that you want to designate as the button to generate the smart action step.
4. In the menu on the right that pops up, scroll down to Smart Actions and select "Create Smart Actions".
5. The "If..." statement will already be filled in and does not need to be changed.  Move on to "Add action" that is under the "Then..." statement.
6. Select Keystroke, then uncheck "Record with fixed delay" and check "Record in advanced mode".
7. Select Start Recording, and then follow the below keystrokes:

   - <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - <kbd>Tab</kbd>
   - <kbd>Tab</kbd>
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Select Stop Recording.
9. Then go back and manually edit each of the time intervals to be 0.021s.
10. Select Confirm, and then Confirm again, and then assign that quick action to your button.

Your designated button should now quickly open the Bluetooth devices that you have paired to your computer.

### Manual Keystrokes:

If you complete steps 1 and 2 above, and do not want to purchase an expensive mouse but just want to know the keystrokes to manually achieve this they are:

- <kbd>Window</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Thanks!

Comment: Is this from ChatGPT?

Comment: No.  Just from me being a Logitech avid device user.